# IF cell in column doesn’t contain specific text then insert formula; otherwise stop execution

Tags: excel, vba

My table looks like:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
| Cell | Cell |
| Cell 5 | cell |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| total | Cell 4 |

I want if column A cell doesn’t contain “total”, insert formula into column C (“column B * 1.2”).
I do not want to overwrite cell in columns C, if cell A contains text “total”. Best case is to stop macro execution.
I need to the check entire column because the number of rows might change.

```vb
Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range
LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each Rng In Range("B:B100" & LstRw)
    Select Case Rng.Value
        Case ""
            Rng(, 3).Formula = "=" & Rng(, 3).Address(0, 0) & "*" & “1.2”
        Case "total"
    End Select
Next Rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write that the keyword `total` is stored in column A, but you are checking column B. Then, you check if the content of column B is *empty* before you write the formula, but your example data shows filled cells so this condition will never be true. Also, your Range definition is wrong (if LastRow is 100, you would loop over Range`"A:B100" & LstRow`, that is `"A:B10000"`

I would suggest to change the code to simply check if the cell contains "total" or not - no `case`-statement needed.

When you write formulas with VBA, it's often easier to use the R1C1-format. The formula in R1C1-format is `=RC[-1]*1.2` (same Row, 1 column to the left).

The following code will stop at the first "total". If you have data below that, simply remove the `Exit For` statement so that the loop continues

```
With ActiveSheet   ' Change this if your code should run on a specific sheet
    Dim LstRow As Long, Rng As Range
    LstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Rng In .Range("A1:A" & LstRow)  ' Change to A2 if your data has a header row
       If lCase(Rng.Value) = "total" Then
           Exit For   ' Will stop at first "total"
       Else
          Rng.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=RC[-1]*1.2"
       End If
    Next Rng
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much FunThomas, I know I might did kids mistake, but with my level below basic your help is priceless, and today I learn something new.
Everything worked just fine, much appreciate buddy.

Comment: @VladislavZinovyev Glad I could help. As you are new to SO: You should take the introduction tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get the idea of SO and learn how it works. If you ask a question and get an answer that answers your question, you should "accept" it. That gives a little bit of reputation to the poster and signals to others that this question is answered.

Comment: where can i "accept" the answer?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work